# Perl - "/" causing issues for splitting by comma

Tags: perl

I'm trying to split a file by ",".  It is a CSV file.

However, one "column" has values that includes "/" and spaces.  And it seems to freak out with that column and does not print anything after that column but moves on to the next row.

My code is simply:

```
perl -lane '@values = split(",",$F[0]);  print $values[0]."\t".$values[3];' basefile.txt > newfile.txt
```

The basefile.txt looks like:

```
"1","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename1"
"2","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename2"
"3","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename3"
```

My newfile.txt should have an output of:

```
"1","filename1"
"2","filename2"
"3","filename3"
```

Instead I get:

```
"1",
"2",
"3",
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the *autosplit* `-a` flag? That way `$F[0]` will contain only the part of the record up to the first space or tab. You should *learn* what each command-line flag does, and not blindly use incantations that "worked before".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the `/` that is confusing perl here, it's the spaces combined with the `-a` flag.  Try:

```
perl -lne '@values = split(",",$_); print $values[0]."\t".$values[3]' basefile
```

Or, better yet, use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) to do the splitting.

Comment: Alternatively specify `-F,` and use `@F` instead of `@values`.

Comment: Re "*use Text::CSV_XS to do the splitting*", This is the only valid answer. The OP obviously has properly quoted CSV (e.g. `1,"foo, bar",..`) that `split` (or `-a`) will mess up

Answer (score 3):

It's not the '/', it's the spaces.

The `-a` flag causes perl to split each line of input and put the fields into the variable `@F`. The delimiter for this split operation is whitespace, unless you override it with the `-F`*delimiter* option on the command line, too.

So for the input

```
"1","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename"
```

with the `-lan` flags specified, perl sets

```
$F[0] = '"1","text","abc';
$F[1] = '//';
$F[2] = '123';
$F[3] = '///';
$F[4] = 'some';
etc.
```

It seems like you just want to do your split operation on the whole line. In which case you should stop using the `-a` flag and just say

```
@values = split(",",$_); ...
```

or leverage the `-a` and `-F...` options and say

```
perl -F/,/ -lane '@values=@F; ...'
```

Comment: This is not working.  the input is a multi-line file, i.e. "1","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename"\n"1","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename"\n"1","text","abc // 123 /// some more text // text","filename"

Comment: @yondaimehokage It's pretty hard to read that in a comment, so you should edit it into your question.

Comment: Also, "not working" is rarely a helpful diagnostic message. Instead you should tell us what happened, including error messages, and explain how it is different from what you expected to happen.

Comment: Fixed question above

Comment: @yondaimehokage Are you splitting `$F[0]` instead of `$_`? The code mob and Tanktalus gave works, so you're doing something else wrong, and without seeing your new code, it's hard to know why.

Comment: That still splits incorrectly (e.g. `1,"foo, bar",..`)